# WordPress Redux framework не работает

Tags: wordpress, framework, redux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает. У меня WordPress Redux framework не работает на хостинге, а на локалке работает. На хостинге при попытке сохранения изменений пишет: "Возникла проблема с вашим действием. Пожалуйста, перезагрузите страницу или попробуйте позже". В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Откройте консоль, там может быть информация об ошибке.

Comment: Скорее всего, сайт перенесли неправильно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220